# TextView(s) or Tableview to work on both paragraphs and single words?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I need to design a view in which:

- A lot of text is presented, with variable paragraph length
- Specific paragraphs can be called into specific parts of the view (top, middle, bottom) either by the user (search, go-to) or programmatically.
- Whenever a paragraph reaches a position in the view (let's say the middle) it triggers an event
- Each paragraph can be tapped/selected to trigger events.
- Each word in the paragraphs can be selected.
- Bonus: the paragraphs are presented continuously, without breaklines (which excludes tableviews).

The text is fixed, and each paragraph is indexed (the data comes from an sqlite database).

I thought of three possible approaches, but each of them have its own problems I could not overcome:

- A single textview. This would let me free to format the text the way I want, and work on the single words. On the other hand, I haven't figure out a way to act on the individual paragraphs. I wouldn't mind adding the index number for each paragraph on the side of the paragraph, but I don't know the best way to tag it (HTML?). Moreover i don't think there is something similar to scrolltoposition for anything other than a tableview.
- Textviews for the individual paragraphs. I could use the index in the database to label each of them. Yet, as above, I don't think there is something similar to scrolltoposition...
- Resizable textviews inside each cell in a tableview. This would let me work easily with the paragraphs and formats, but I don't think the text within the cell is selectable.

Any advice on how to solve those specific problems?
Any suggestion of an alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach, by far, is the UITableView. Everything you have listed is easily accomplished with the delegate methods of UITableViewDelegate, and UIScrollViewDelegate (of which a table view calls). The only issue with the tableview is the fact that UILabels cannot be selected within them. This is easily solved by not using a UILabel, but a UITextView. Simply disable scrolling on the text view, and disable editing (I'm not sure if disabling editing removes the selectability. If it does, override the UITextView and block edits from there).

> **1. Use UITableView**
>
> **2. Create UITableViewCell with UIScrollView inside it**
>
> **3. Override UIScrollView to disable editing**
>
> **4. Add logic to UITableViewDelegate and UIScrollViewDelegate (of the table view) for the taps and position events**

good luck,

ZR

Comment: Thanks a lot. <br/> Should I use a UITextView or a UIScrollview?

Comment: @silvoc I do not know if disabling editing disables selecting too. I recommend trying it out (literally one line of code to test this), and if it doesn't, you can subclass UITextView and block the begin editing calls from working. ALSO, you can use the UITextViewDelegate and return false on textViewShouldBeginEditing

Comment: @silvoc oops, i started responding before your edit. Use a UITextView, disable scrolling on the UITextView, put it inside a UITableViewCell, and then make a UITableView with the same number of rows as there are paragraphs.